# How to check if web image exists and server makes a redirect?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have mobile app (Xamarin Forms for Android and iOS).  I need to display some pictures from the server in my application. some pictures do not exist on the server. if the picture does not exist, the server redirects to another page. I need to check in the client if this picture exists, the owner cannot change the server logic. I have two options for checking:

1. Make a request to the server. I use this code:

   ```
   HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("url");
   request.Method = "HEAD";
   bool exists;
   try
   {
    request.GetResponse();
    exists = true;
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
     exists = false;
   }
   ```

but I don't get an exception because the server redirects and returns a different page.

2. Download a file and check if it is an png or html page. this option seems a little complicated to
   me.

any advice and tips  - I'll be grateful.

Comment: use HttpClient to request the image url and check if the response code is 200 for success or 3xx for redirect.  However, if the server is doing a redirect without using a 3xx response then you will have to download the file and inspect it

Comment: You can check content type header of response. If it's image/... then it should be image.